# Firebase: How to read of children from different child in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i know the question up there is confusing but here what i want to read from firebase in explained manner:

[image]

As it obvious from the image, i want retreive all circled **three** child's "route_name" and conosle log it in javascript.
To do that i try like this:

```
var buses_Ref = firebase.database().ref('online_drivers/');
buses_Ref.on('child_added', function (data) {
     console.log(data.val().route_name);
});
```

But it showing **undefined**

[image]

And if I tried to console log **data** it will showing this, which i think are the two children **Jigjiga** and **Siinaay**

```
console.log(data);
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the data structure that is coming through as `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two nested dynamic child nodes under `online_drivers`. By using `child_added` Firebase takes care of one of those already, but you'll need to handle the other level in your callback code.

The easiest way to do this is with `DataSnapshot.forEach()`:

```
buses_Ref.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log(data.val().route_name);
  })
});
```